# How to justify text only visually (not change the buffer text)?

Tags: visual-line-mode, justification

Is there a way in Emacs Org mode to have the text appear justified on the screen regardless of the size of the window/frame?

That is, not alter the buffer text itself (filling, justifying), but just visually filling and justifying.

For instance, it is left-aligned by default:
[image]

Comment: Please clarify what you mean, e.g., by "justified *on screen*". And what does the question in the body (which is about Org mode) have to do with the question in the title (which is about "visual mode").

Comment: I have added some clarification, thanks!

Comment: Still not clear to me. Are you asking about justifying the text, as in changing the text itself, so that it's justified, or just visually wrapping and justifying it, without changing the text itself. Normally, Emacs functions that "justify" text do the former.

Comment: Are you using `visual-line-mode`?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to justify just the appearance (i.e., not changing the text). If you don't get an answer to that request then consider filing an enhancement request for `visual-line-mode` to be able to also justify (in different ways: left, right, both). Do that with `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: I've edited the question, assuming that you mean visual-only justification. (And I imagine that your request need not be limited to Org mode. If so, consider removing that tag and mention of Org mode.)

Comment: Yes! I am using visual-line-mode. So then I assume there is not to justify the appearance? What would be the alternative of "changing" the text? I am not sure what this means. I just want it justified :)